# Pulling and saving information from Graph API

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

A couple issues.

Issue 1: Trace "Made it in!!!" registers, but I can't get anything inside the onCompleted to trace. Yet, in my App, I'm logged in to my Facebook account.

Issue 2: When I get userId to modify within the onCompleted, I can't get the results to modify the "outside of scope" String

```
String userId;


        // If session is open
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {    
            Log.d("Trace","Made it in!!!");

            //  Make an API call to get user data
            // and define a new callback to handle the response
            Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    Log.d("Trace","Starting onComplete");
                    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

                    // If current session matches active session
                    if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                        Log.d("Trace","Session is active.");
                        if (user != null) {

                            // Set the Textview's text from user's id
                            userId = user.getId();
                            Log.d("Trace", "userId after PULL FROM GRAPH: " + userId);
                            //Log.d("Trace", userId);

                        } // end if user != null   
                    }   // end if session == Session.getActiveSession()                 
                } // end onCompleted
            }); // end request
        } // end session open check
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue 1: you've created the request, but you're not executing it. Try adding request.executeAsync() after you've created the request. Alternatively, you can also call the Request.executeMeRequestAsync(Session, Callback) method to execute the request immediately.

Issue 2: this is a limitation of Java. What you're creating with the GraphUserCallback is an anonymous inner class, and you cannot directly modify state outside of the class. One quick way to solve this is to use an instance variable (declare userId inside your class) rather than a temporary variable (declared in a method).